# is redshift still true if object emitting is not moving away but the observer is

Tags: visible-light, doppler-effect

If something is moving away fast it's color would appear redder than its actual color due to phenomenon known as Doppler effect.

But what if the object isn't moving but i am moving away faster would that still affect the way waves travel.

Optional:-

And why. Object emitting isn't moving. And won't that means that doppler effect is subjective. What does that say about light and its wavelength?

Comment: Motion is *relative*.  What is absolute is that you and the object are moving *with respect to each other*.  You are at rest with respect to yourself.  The object is moving with respect to you.  Which one of you is *actually* moving?  There is no absolute rest so that question is meaningless.

Comment: is there any reason to give negative vote?

Comment: How do YOU know, which is moving ??  could be that's the down vote. (not mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are moving away from an object, then the same redshift will be observed as the if the object you are observing is moving away at the same speed. This is because of the relativistic doppler effect, the equation going like this $$\lambda_O = \sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}}\lambda_e$$

where $\lambda_O$ is the observed wavelength and $\lambda_e$ is the emitted wavelength, and $v$ is the relative velocity between you and the object (see how it doesn't matter whether or not you or the object is moving?). The reason that the wavelength is effected in both cases and because of the following. Say you are stationary and and you are receiving radiation. You will see the radiation at it's normal wavelength. Now if you travel **away** from the radiation, between each crest of the wave, there will actually be a greater time interval, since the radiation must "catch up to you". While this difference is usually pretty small, it still can effect the color of light. The diagrams on the wiki page illustrate it pretty well

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect